# WSGI .htaccess with addon domain

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wsgi

I have a subfolder in which I am running a wsgi app. I also have an addon domain pointing to this subfolder. I have trouble setting up the .htaccess file in the subfolder.

My current file structure:

```
public_html/
  .htaccess
  irrelevant index.html
  some other irrelevant stuff
  sub_folder/
    .htaccess
    app.wsgi
```

I have a maindomain.com pointing to /public_html/, and an addondomain.com pointing to /sub_folder/. 
Currently the .htaccess file in the root folder is empty, the one in sub_folder is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(app\.wsgi/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.wsgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works if I go to addondomain.com, but gives me a 404 when I go to maindomain.com/sub_folder. The log shows that it looks for /public_html/app.wsgi then, instead of /public_html/sub_folder/app.wsgi. How can I rewrite the .htaccess to make it work in both scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with add-on domain as well.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(app\.wsgi/.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub_folder/(.*)$ sub_folder/app.wsgi/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(sub_folder/)?(.*)$ app.wsgi/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

***EDIT** :*

The rules above need to be tweaked since OP's `.htaccess` is already within `/sub_folder`. The ones above would still work if anyone wants their root `/.htaccess` to be in the driving seat.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(app\.wsgi/.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub_folder/app.wsgi/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.wsgi/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: With this RewriteCond, it doesn't work with maindomain.com/sub_folder, because in that case nothing gets redirected to app.wsgi. I tried to answer it myself with this as a start, but it doesn't work completely yet. Please see my own answer. (I'm still hesitating wether I should've put it as an edit or an answer is fine here.)

Answer (score 1):

I made it work, sort of...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(app\.wsgi/.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub_folder [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub_folder/app.wsgi/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub_folder[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.wsgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

@Ravi's answer works with addondomain.com, but not with maindomain.com/sub_folder, because in that case the index is showed, because it is not redirected to app.wsgi.

To solve this, I added a second RewriteCond and RewriteRule. The problem now is, it doesn't work when you go to addondomain.com/sub_folder (although that *shouldn't* happen). So if there is a better answer that also handles that properly, please enlighten me. Otherwise I'll just hope that that situation doesn't happen.

Edit:

This works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(app\.wsgi/.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub_folder/app.wsgi/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.wsgi/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Ravi's exact code didn't work, because this .htaccess is in the sub_folder, so the `^(.*)$` part is only the stuff after sub_folder/, somehow. But modified like this it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Isn't this redirecting maindomain/sub to maindomain/sub/wsgi/sub? Anyways, I've added an update to help with the add-on domain as well.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't...  
But I updated it based on your update and now it works perfectly!